# Extracting multiple fields from one list and save it to another list or same type new list. In java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of user `List<User>` "abc".

```
class User {
int id;
String name;
String address;
.....//getters and setters
}
```

I only need to extract name and address from the `List<User>` and save to another new list object `List<User>` "xyz". Or some new list which have two String fields name and address. e.g.:

```
class SomeClass {
String name;
String address;
........//getters and setters
}
```

I know that it can be done by iterating the original list and save to another new list object. But I want to know that how it can be done in `Java 8` more efficiently. By using `streams()`, `map()`… etc. And with using default constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<SomeClass> list = users.stream()
                            .map(user -> new SomeClass(user.getName(), user.getAddress()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have implemented this logic which needs a parameterised constructor. Is it possible without constructor ??

Comment: How do you normally create an instance of SomeClass? Replace with that code in the lambda.

Comment: Can u be more descriptive ?? with example. I mean without instantiating class.

Comment: I think it would be better if you could give your example of parameterised class with constructor

Comment: you can replace the lambda with any setters you call e.g. `user -> {sc = new SomeClass(); sc.setName(user.getName(); return sc;}` It becomes a bit more verbose though.

Comment: Ash French's suggestion is good but it's verbose though. So I think for less verbosity conscells suggestion is good. So is there any other way, if any ? :) On performance basis.

Comment: If you absolutely want every bit of performance use the good old for loop (not the for-each one with iterator). Although what you gain will be very minute to be noticeable in a typical application.

Comment: @conscells you mean loops are faster than lambdas??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne See https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html. Again in most cases they are too small to be noticeable.

Comment: I want to do it with out a `SomeClass` I dont like to create a class everytime i am testing